# typeahead js 'No Result Found' message when there is no suggetion rails bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, autocomplete, typeahead.js

In rails 3.2 application I want to display suggestion in autocomplete when i type to textbox.

I use typeahead.js for bootstrap 3.

I am not able to display "No Result Found". following is my code.

```
$('.js_edit_set_type_ahead').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
            person = [];
            map = {};

            var data = [
                <% @people.order(:last_name).each do |person| %> {
                    "id": "<%= person.id %>",
                    "name": "<%= person.full_name %>"
                },
                <% end %>
            ];

            $.each(data, function(i, state) {
                map[state.name] = state;
                person.push(state.name);
            });

            process(person);

        },
        updater: function(item) {
            selectedState = map[item].id;
            $this.prev().val(selectedState)

            return item;
        },
        matcher: function(item) {
            if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                $this.prev().val('')
                    // $(".add_member_btn").removeClass('hide')
                    // $(".person_details").val('')
                    // $(".person_details").removeAttr('disabled')
                return true;
            }
        },
        items: 'all',
        sorter: function(items) {
            return items;
        },
        highlighter: function(item) {
            // $(".add_member_btn").removeClass('hide')
            var regex = new RegExp('(' + this.query + ')', 'gi');
            return item.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
        }
    });
})
```

Thanks